# Lazy mode of recursive function

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, lazy-evaluation

I'm going to find a solution to this problem:

Splitting given list to sublist with given sub-list length and skip length, for example:

```haskell
groupEvery 3 1 [1..6] = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [4,5,6]]
groupEvery 3 2 "abcdefghij" = [ "abc", "cde", "efg", "ghi", "ij"]
```

The `groupEvery n p l` args details are:

- n is length of sub-list: Int
- f is length of skip: Int
- xs is input list: [a]

Here is my solution:

```haskell
groupEvery :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
groupEvery n p xs acc
    | length xs <= n = acc ++ [xs]
    | otherwise = groupEvery n p dropped (acc++[segment])
        where
            dropped = drop p xs
            segment = take n xs
```

But this solution is not lazy, for example `take 3 Lib2.groupEvery 3 1 [1..] []` never finished.
My question is about

- Better solutions for the `groupEvery` function ?
- How we can write recursive lazy function that accumulate some data ? In other words is there any structure for this kind of recursive functions that accumulate results and are lazy ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem is that you use an accumulator and only return the list when you walked over the entire input list. Furthermore `length l` will  walk through the entire list. You don't need to calculate the length. This is also inefficient: if the list is long it will each time make a linear run.

You can pattern match on the list and for an empty list return an empty list and for a non-empty list yield the `take n xs` and recurse with `drop p xs`.

```
groupEvery :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupEvery _ _ [] = []
groupEvery n p xs = take n xs : groupEvery n p (drop p xs)
```

This thus produces:

```
ghci> take 3 (groupEvery 3 1 [1..])
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]
```

You can further improve the function by combining `take n` and `drop p` such that you only walk over the `min n p` parts of the list once. I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Then I guess if we want to have a lazy function we can't use accumulator ?

Comment: @S4eed3sm: well what is important is that you do not keep recursively calling the function until the end of the list before "yielding" results. If you for example need to calculate the sum at the same time, you can use an accumulator that holds the sum. But indeed, using an accumulator as described in the question is probably not a good option in most Haskell programs.

Comment: could you explain more about improvements that you explained upper.

Comment: @S4eed3sm: the implementation of [**`splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt) is equivalent to `splitAt n xs = (take n xs, drop n xs)`, but is [implemented](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#splitAt) with explicit recursion to avoid walking the same part of the list twice: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#splitAt you can make a variant of this that will walk the common part of `take n` and `drop p` to avoid "walking that part twice".

Answer (score 1):

Your use of "accumulator" here is vague.

The useful nomenclature is "state passing and building up", "output list creation", "tail recursion", and "guarded recursion" otherwise known as "tail recursion modulo cons" in the strict setting.

Yes, we can create the output list gradually through guarded recursion while simultaneously arranging for passing and accumulating / building up the state from one invocation to the next:

```
makeList elt next state = go state
  where
  go state = elt state : go (next state)
  --- which is just
  -- go = map elt . iterate next
```

(*"guarded"* recursion, guarded by a *lazy* data constructor, here `:`).

Specifically, your example is

```
groupEvery n p  =  makeList (take n) (drop p)
```

up to a termination condition:

```
> takeWhile (not . null) $ groupEvery 3 2 [1..20]
[[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7],[7,8,9],[9,10,11],[11,12,13],
 [13,14,15],[15,16,17],[17,18,19],[19,20]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your  solution. I checked your solution but `takeWhile (not . null) $ groupEvery 3 2 [1..]` dosen't terminated and goes to infinit. I think your solution is not lazy.

Comment: incorrect. it does not terminate _while producing the result list, element by element_. which is the definition of being properly lazy. :) if you want to stop it, tack another `take 20` on top of it.

Comment: Correct, my mistake, `take 3 $ takeWhile (not . null) $ groupEvery 3 2 [1..]` is worked.

Comment: (also notice, I defined `groupEvery`, not `groupEvery2`).

Comment: I change your solution as: `go state = case elt state of [] -> []; _ -> elt state : go (next state)` and by this we don't need the `takeWhile (not . null) ` part.

Comment: please post new, focused question, with all the specific relevant code in it, _as is_; and the desired and actual output. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241956/discussion-between-s4eed3sm-and-will-ness).